How to create a qemu vm with two disk
I need to create a vm with qemu with two disk, so the second disk appears as second device with name i.e. /dev/sdb
To create with a vm with single disk:
qemu-img create -f qcow2 alpine.qcow2 16G

qemu-system-x86_64 \
-enable-kvm \
-m 2048 \
-nic user,model=virtio \
-drive file=alpine.qcow2,media=disk,if=virtio \
-cdrom alpine-standard-3.8.0-x86_64.iso \
-sdl

tryed to use virt-manager but there is no such option
How to create a qemu vm with two hard disks?

in virt-manager add hardware - then storage is the first choice
